# When one ajax is SUCCESS load next

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, queue

I have been looking into a jQuery Ajax queue system. I have a step by step generator. It generates a pdf and then once the pdf is generated an image is created. Once these 2 processes are complete I then send an email confirmation. It must also be flexible to add additional steps.

However, I have yet to find an example that works. They all use 'COMPLETE' rather than 'success' so if I return an error via jSON then it is ignored. It moves on to the next in the queue

Any ideas?

EDIT

It's quite complex whats happening.

My plugin (copied from another plugin)

```
        $.AjaxQueue = function() {
          this.reqs = [];
          this.requesting = false;
        };
        $.AjaxQueue.prototype = {
          add: function(req) {
            this.reqs.push(req);
            this.next();
          },
          next: function() {
            if (this.reqs.length == 0)
              return;

            if (this.requesting == true)
              return;

            var req = this.reqs.splice(0, 1)[0];
            var complete = req.complete;
            var self = this;
            if (req._run)
              req._run(req);
            req.complete = function() {
              if (complete)
                complete.apply(this, arguments);
              self.requesting = false;
              self.next();
            }

            this.requesting = true;
            $.ajax(req);
          }
    };
```

I have also written a function to speed my code up

```
function createQueue(file, inputid, step, params) {

        var queue   = new $.AjaxQueue();
            queue.add({
                url: file,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                data: params,
                  complete : function(data, status) {
                      $('li#step' + step + ' .loading').remove();
                      // DO SOMETHING. CANT CHECK FOR ERRORS
                  },
                  success : function(data, status) {
                      // DOES NOT WORK 
                  },
                  error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
                    console.log(xhr);
                    console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
                  },
                  _run: function(req) {
                    //special pre-processor to alter the request just before it is finally executed in the queue
                    //req.url = 'changed_url'
                    $('li#step' + step).append('<span class="loading"></span>');
                  }
            });

    }
```

Step 1. I am using mpdf to generate a pdf. Now this takes a few seconds to actually build depending on theme, images used etc. So i call this:

```
createQueue('post_pdf.php', id, 1, { 'filename': filename + '.pdf', 'id': id, 'crop': crop } );
```

Step 2 - Generate some images

```
createQueue('ajax_image.php', id, 2, { 'filename': filename + '.pdf' } );
```

Step 3 - (something else like send email summary)

```
createQueue('mail.php', id, 3, { 'from': 'newfilename', 'to': 'emavle@pb.com', 'subject': 'This is a subject', 'body': 'Body Copy' } );
```

If it fails at step 1 I can see it in console but its not returned

Comment: Curious why you need multiple ajax requests and can't make one request and let server manage the other steps? Please show the code that is giving you problems

Comment: Hi, can you post a sample code so it easy to understand what exactly you want to do and what you are currently doing.

Answer (score 0):

As @charlietfl suggested, have each step in PHP on server side. After the AJAX call is done, you can have the response from the server and continue based on that. Example:

```
// make AJAX request to file.php and send 'data'
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "file.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: { data }
});

// when PHP is done, receive the output and act accordingly
request.done(function( msg ) {
  if (msg == "A") {
    // plan A
  } else if (msg == "B") {
    // plan B
  }
});
```